# Fill an arraylist with repeated HTTP Request's Response Data on Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to process a specific URL (that returns different numbers each time) and get its return into an array to use it in another HTTP Request.

My test is built like this:

- Loop Controller (2 loops)

  - HTTP Request

```
        JSON Extractor
        Reference Name: myVar
        Match No.: -1
        Compute concatenation var: checked
```

- Debug Sampler

When this block is executed, when I check the Debug Sampler's Response Data, it always fills the variable myVar with the last occurrence, like this:

```
myVar_1=
myVar_1_g=0
myVar_1_g0=3154
myVar_matchNr=1
```

Shouldn't it also store something like `myVar_2`, since I defined the "Match No.:" as **-1 **?

I read some answers as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878136/jmeter-json-extractor-extract-all-values-of-one-key-in-a-string) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823556/looping-through-json-response-in-jmeter) but my problem is that I need to iterate a variable with some response data, no matter how many times it is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that on each iteration of the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) your `myVar` variable **gets overwritten**

If you want to store `myVar` variable value for each loop you should amend its reference name to look like:

```
myVar${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}
```

Then given you have 2 iterations of the Loop Controller you will have the following variables defined when the loop ends:

```
myVar0=xxxx
myVar1=yyyy
```

The `${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}` variable is available since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4/)